# d3js Multibar - spread top/bottom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a chart like the picture here. That features a top/bottom bars -

[image]

I've currently got a malfunction on rendering the bottom bars - where it needs to sit under the horizontal plane, expand from the centre point. How do I fix the chart to render something closer to the example.

current code
https://jsfiddle.net/2v5w8hea/

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>multibar d3</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>



    <script>
 
        
        d3.select("body")
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        var data = [{"label": "Toblerone", "value": 10},{"label": "Snickers", "value": 25},{"label": "Jawbreakers", "value": 60,},{"label": "Gummi Worms", "value": 20,}];

        var width = parseInt(900, 10),
            height = parseInt(800, 10);


        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#046395', '#d62828', '#f77f00', '#fcbf49', '#eae2b7']);


        data.forEach(function(d) {
          d.total = +d.value;
        });

        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 85,
            left: 25
          },
          w = width - margin.left - margin.right,
          h = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scaleBand()
          .range([0, w])
          .padding(0.9);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([h, 0]);

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
          return d.label;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d.total;
        })]);

        var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr('class', 'lollipopchart')
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var multibar = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'multibar');

        var topbars = multibar
          .append("g")
          .attr('class', 'topbars')

        topbars.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.label);
          })
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .attr("y", h)
          .transition()
          .duration(1500)
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return h - y(d.total);
          });

        var bottombars = multibar
          .append("g")
          .attr('class', 'bottombars')

        bottombars.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return color(i);
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.label);
          })
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
          .attr("y", -h)
          .transition()
          .duration(1500)
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.value);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return h - y(d.total);
          });
        




    </script>



    </body>
</html>
```